# How to add progress bar using Android Studio for React Native projects?

Tags: java, react-native, android-studio, splash-screen

I am using [React Native splash screen](https://github.com/crazycodeboy/react-native-splash-screen) to add splash screen in Android & iOS. This is the content of `laucnh_screen.xml` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

    android:background="@color/lightblue">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="180dp"
        android:layout_height="180dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:src="@drawable/logo" />


   <ProgressBar
       android:id="@+id/progress"
       style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
       android:layout_centerInParent="true"
       android:layout_marginStart="56dp"
       android:layout_marginEnd="56dp"
       android:layout_marginBottom="60dp"
       android:indeterminateBehavior="repeat"
       android:indeterminateDuration="10"
       android:max="100"
       android:minHeight="2dip"
       android:progress="10"
       android:progressBackgroundTint="@color/green_text"
       android:progressBackgroundTintMode="multiply"
       android:progressTintMode="add" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

How do I animate & load this progress bar so when the app is ready and it reaches 100%, the main screen shows up? I am not a Java developer, I guess this might load it:

```
R.id.progress.setProgress(25);
R.id.progress.setProgress(50);
R.id.progress.setProgress(75);
```

But I don't know the rest, where do I write above code? when I need to set it to 100% and redirect it to main screen?

Any help is appreciated.

Thank you in advance.